# Commenting inside a program body in different Programming languages

Tags: comments

Can anyone tell me the different ways of commenting and what is the difference between `/*` and `//` type of commenting? I have used both and i have found `/*` one more useful but i couldn't understand the real difference.

Answer (score 0):

In many languages `//` is used for a single line comment and `/* */` is a multi-line comment and in java `/** */` is used by javadoc to create documentation from your code.  Commenting is just user preference, unless you are using something like javadoc. If you are using a compiled language, it is stripped out before it compiles.  You can check out all the various types of commenting in many programming languages [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_%28computer_programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

/** is useful too because software like doxygene read it
to generate a documentation fort function's core